# Why do I keep getting error CS0246? (ASP.NET Core MVC)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to create a simple web application with .NET Core MVC but I'm pretty new to it. I'm getting an error

> CS0246 - the type or namespace name 'AgeTodayModel' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I've looked everywhere and can't figure out what I'm missing. Here's my `Index.cshtml` file where the error occurs:

```
@model AgeTodayModel
```

And here's the `AgeTodayModel.cs` model file:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace AgeToday.Models
{
    public class AgeTodayModel
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a name.")]
        public string? UsersName { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a year of birth.")]
        [Range(1900, 2022, ErrorMessage =
               "Year of birth must be between 1900 and 2022.")]
        public int BirthYear { get; set; }

        public decimal? AgeThisYear()
        {
            int THIS_YEAR = 2022;
            int ageToday = THIS_YEAR - BirthYear;
            return ageToday;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That type is `AgeToday.Models.AgeTodayModel`, not just `AgeTodayModel`

Answer (score 0):

add a model namespace to the view

```
@using AgeToday.Models

@model AgeTodayModel
```